# How to calculate time complexity for the given algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

Can you please share your thoughts on what will be time complexity for this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++) {

            for(int j = n - i; j > n/2; j--) {

            }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @bfontaine thanks for pointing it out, I should have listed my findings. I did try to find operation count for size N like
 N=32 --136 ; N=64 -- 528 ; N=Math.pow(2, 20) ; 137439215616. I found that these operation counts are nearly 1/7th of N square. I was looking for Stackoverflow members thoughts on ways to calculate time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to compute the number of times you execute your operation :

[image]

Hence, the complexity is `O(n²)`.

Comment: Thank you. I calculated for different input size, I've noticed computing time is near 1/7th of Math.pow(n,2)                                            
           N size                       Operations count
   32    136
    64    528
    Math.pow(2, 20)      137439215616

Comment: you're missing parentheses in the Sum after first `=`. Your i is outside the sum.. I would also recommend using another end.`...=(n^2+n)/8 \inO(n^2)`. This might help the OP that the O(f) is a set.

Comment: @xenteros It's true my notation was ambiguous. I think you're right. I modified accordingly.